# How can I get the native PIXI object from a react-pixi-fiber React component?

Tags: reactjs, pixi.js

In an app wrapped with `withApp` from this:

```
import { withApp } from "react-pixi-fiber";
```

And some code that looks a little like this:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
  // ...
  eventHandler(evt) {
    console.log("Event target =", evt.target);
  }

  render() {
    let comp = (<Sprite interactive texture={...} pointerup={eventHandler} {/* ... */} />);
    console.log("Component =", comp);
    return (comp);
  }
}
```

Doing this, the object that is logged as the "Event target" is a native PIXI Sprite object, which gives me access to methods like `getBounds()`.  I'd like to be able to access this same sort of data from the `comp` variable (which I would then store somewhere), but when I log that, the object I get is something different.  It has a `$$typeof: Symbol(react.element)`, so I presume it's just a React object.  I'd like to find a way to get access to the PIXI object associated with it so that I can do use that object later for doing things like bounds checking on an interactive setup with various other elements.

Is there a way to do this?  Or: How can I do bounds checking on interactivity into an object that isn't the current target of an event from e.g. `pointerup`, `pointermove`, etc.?

Comment: I think the last sentence is the question you need to solve. I suspect that if the library doesn't easily expose the native PIXI object, then you aren't meant to interact with it directly. I'm not familiar with this libraries, though, so I can't offer any specific direction here.

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while, but if you're still looking to solve this, you need to use a `ref` on your `Sprite` component. This isn't specific to `react-pix-fiber`, just standard React behavior. Using ReactDOM the ref would give you access to the html element, with PIXI and react-pixi-fiber, it gives you the PIXI display object.

```
import React, { createRef, Component } from "react";

class Foo extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.ref = createRef();
  }

  eventHandler() {
    console.log(this.ref.current);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Sprite
        interactive
        texture={...}
        pointerup={this.eventHandler.bind(this)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Besides the event handler, `this.ref` will be available in other lifecycle methods. Before `render` though, `this.ref.current` will be undefined.

Alternatively, you could use function components and hooks, either the `useCallback` hook or a combination for `useRef` and `useEffect`.

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

const Foo = () => {
  const ref = useCallback(sprite => {
    console.log(sprite);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Sprite
      interactive
      ref={ref}
      texture={...}
      pointerup={this.eventHandler.bind(this)}
    />
  );
}
```

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";

const Foo = () => {
  const ref = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(ref.current);
  }, []);

  return (
    <Sprite
      interactive
      ref={ref}
      texture={...}
      pointerup={this.eventHandler.bind(this)}
    />
  );
}
```

I created working examples of each of these methods here (see the `BunnyClass`, `BunnyCallback` and `BunnyRef` files):
https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-maxwell-pirh3